# Configure Angular to use playwright

Tags: angular, protractor, karma-jasmine, puppeteer, playwright

I'm going to preface this by saying I don't know [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) well but as it seems like [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) was created to be its successor so I thought I'd just skip directly to using it.

Using this [guide](https://www.digestibledevops.com/devops/2018/09/18/puppeteer-with-angular.html) I've attempted to configure Karma and Protractor just as I would `puppeteer` only substituting  `playwright` wherever I was told to put `puppeteer` instead.

This line

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('playwright').executablePath();
```

Doesn't work however as `playwright` doesn't have an `exectablePath()` function itself

Instead I tried

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('playwright').chromium.executablePath()
```

Which seemed like it would do what I wanted. however I'm still getting the following error message. when trying to run `ng test --watch=false`

```
 40% building 84/84 modules 0 active15 02 2020 20:41:52.310:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (2/2).
15 02 2020 20:41:52.360:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
        /workspace/vr2k2/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-chromium/linux-740847/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

15 02 2020 20:41:52.360:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout: 
15 02 2020 20:41:52.361:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: /workspace/vr2k2/node_modules/playwright-core/.local-chromium/linux-740847/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

15 02 2020 20:41:52.436:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
```

Anyone have a better resource on how to setup Angular with `playwright`?

Comment: do you overwright process.env somewhere in your setup?

Comment: Did you add playwright-core instead of playwright?

Comment: `  "playwright": "^0.11.1", `  this is what is in my package.json file. So I don't *think* so

Comment: In my karm.config.js file
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('playwright').chromium.executablePath()

In my protractor.conf.js file

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('playwright').chromium.executablePath();
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

Answer (score 2):

The error string shows that Chromium is unable to find a shared library (`libx11`). This typically implies that your system is missing system dependencies. If you are on Ubuntu, you can use [this list of system dependencies](https://github.com/arjun27/playwright-github-actions/blob/master/Dockerfile#L8) for the 3 bundled browsers.